# How to show Your time and Our time clock using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

On my website, I want to show my local time as **Our Time** and Visitor time as **Your time**. Now, I have this JS code:

```
<script>
    function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    var session = "AM";

    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }

    if(h > 12){
        h = h - 12;
        session = "PM";
    }

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + session;
    document.getElementById("our_time").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("our_time").textContent = time;

    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

}
showTime();
</script>
```

It's showing my Local time.

Now, will I use same code to show the Visitor time or is there anything I need to change?

Comment: Yes `document.getElementById("our_time")` and `document.getElementById("our_time").textContent` you have to change

Comment: I am not getting you properly what is the difference b/w our time and your time ?

Comment: This will always show the Timezone of the CLIENT. In order to show your time you will have to convert “our time” to your timezone.

Comment: For example go to this site: https://trendytheme.net/support/ and check the right sidebar. It will be shown Your Time and Website Owner Local Time.

Comment: @SourabhSomani I don't' understand. Can you show me?

Comment: @Ood can you tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know your timezone (a list of timezones can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) then use it with [`date.toLocaleTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) like this :

```js
const locale = 'en-US';
const our_timeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
// refresh time every second
setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById('our_time').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(locale, { timeStyle: 'long', timeZone: our_timeZone });
  document.getElementById('your_time').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleTimeString(locale, { timeStyle: 'long' });
}, 1);
```

```html
<p>Our time</p>
<span id="our_time"></span>
<p>Your time</p>
<span id="your_time"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe your approach is wrong.

a) our time(website time): this should come from a server(and perhaps sync with it in a regular intervel )

b) your time(user's local time): new Date() will do this part since it runs on the client(browser).

this is a sample json data from "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Salta"
Oh! it's also free.. hook your ajax call with relevent timezone

> {    "week_number":49,    "utc_offset":"-03:00",
>   "utc_datetime":"2019-12-03T11:42:02.994093+00:00",
>   "unixtime":1575373322,    "timezone":"America/Argentina/Salta",
>   "raw_offset":-10800,    "dst_until":null,    "dst_offset":0,
>   "dst_from":null,    "dst":false,    "day_of_year":337,
>   "day_of_week":2,    "datetime":"2019-12-03T08:42:02.994093-03:00",
>   "client_ip":"hi hi hi... almost had me there",    "abbreviation":"-03" }

also, try this piece of code..

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
```

which will give an output

> "5:23 PM"

ps: this is just a suggestion..

Comment: Does server time mean where I host my website? Like goDaddy, NameCheap etc?

Comment: @creativeartbd Normally 'our time' should reflect where your business is registered/operating/located - just make interval-calls from the backend (php, node or whatever) to ntp-server located in your time-zone..

Comment: a bit confused. I hosted my website on goDaddy. So my web server is on goDaddy, right? from where the time will show as server time?

Comment: http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/--try your timezone here--
checkout http://worldtimeapi.org/ this and you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

Get timezone of client using

```
const localDate = new Date(1489199400000);

localDate.getTimeZoneOffset();//time zone offset
```

then use this value in in Date and get the difference of your time and clients machine time

Comment: is this `1489199400000` is needed and why?

Comment: thats the time stamp.

Comment: you can get current timestamp by 
const currrentTimestamp = +new Date